# Get user's current location - Kotlin

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin, google-api, location

Guys, I am trying to get a user location but there is something wrong, when I run my app there is no player icon and the location is wrong - it still shows lat = 0.0, lon = 0.0. I don't use an emulator, I test app on my mobile phone (Android 4.4.2 if it matters). Please take a look at my code maybe I just can't see a mistake. Thank you in advance!

```
class MapsActivity : FragmentActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {

private var mMap: GoogleMap? = null

private val USER_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE = 1000

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps)
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
        .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)

    requestLocationPermission()
}

/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap
}

//ask permission
private fun requestLocationPermission() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) !=
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            requestPermissions(
                arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
                USER_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE
            )
        }
    }
}


fun GetPlayerLocation() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "User location access on", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

    var playerLocation = PlayerLocationListener()

    var locationManager = getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 3, 3f, playerLocation)

    var mythread = myThread()
    mythread.start()
}

override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {

    when (requestCode) {

        USER_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE -> {

            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                GetPlayerLocation()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "We cannot access to your location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
    }
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
}

var location: Location? = null

// Get player location
inner class PlayerLocationListener : LocationListener {

    constructor() {
        location = Location("Start")
        location!!.latitude = 0.0
        location!!.longitude = 0.0
    }

    override fun onStatusChanged(p0: String?, p1: Int, p2: Bundle?) {
    }

    override fun onProviderEnabled(p0: String?) {
    }

    override fun onProviderDisabled(p0: String?) {
    }

    override fun onLocationChanged(p0: Location?) {
        location = p0
    }

}

inner class myThread : Thread {
    constructor() : super(){

    }
    override fun run() {

        while (true) {

            try {
                runOnUiThread {

                    mMap!!.clear()
                    val sydney = LatLng(location!!.latitude, location!!.longitude)
                    mMap!!.addMarker(
                        MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Hi!")
                            .snippet("Let's go!")
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.player)))
                    mMap!!.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 14f))
                }
                Thread.sleep(1000)

            } catch (ex: Exception) {
            }
        }
    }

}
```

}

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this way

implement in gradle these dependency

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.4.0'
```

uses permission in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

create a `locationListener` interface

```
interface locationListener {
    fun locationResponse(locationResult: LocationResult)
}
```

then create a `Location.kt` class

```
class Location (var activity: AppCompatActivity, locationListener: locationListener){
    private val permissionFineLocation=android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
    private val permissionCoarseLocation=android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION

    private val REQUEST_CODE_LOCATION=100

    private var fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient?=null

    private var locationRequest: LocationRequest?=null
    private var callbabck: LocationCallback?=null
    init {
        fusedLocationClient= FusedLocationProviderClient(activity.applicationContext)

        inicializeLocationRequest()
        callbabck=object: LocationCallback(){
            override fun onLocationResult(p0: LocationResult?) {
                super.onLocationResult(p0)

                locationListener.locationResponse(p0!!)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun inicializeLocationRequest() {
        locationRequest= LocationRequest()
        locationRequest?.interval=50000
        locationRequest?.fastestInterval=5000
        locationRequest?.priority=LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
    }
    private fun validatePermissionsLocation():Boolean{
        val fineLocationAvailable= ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity.applicationContext, permissionFineLocation)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        val coarseLocationAvailable=ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity.applicationContext, permissionCoarseLocation)==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED

        return fineLocationAvailable && coarseLocationAvailable
    }
    private fun requestPermissions(){
        val contextProvider=ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity, permissionFineLocation)

        if(contextProvider){
            Toast.makeText(activity.applicationContext, "Permission is required to obtain location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        permissionRequest()
    }
    private fun permissionRequest(){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, arrayOf(permissionFineLocation, permissionCoarseLocation), REQUEST_CODE_LOCATION)
    }
    fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode:Int, permissions:Array<out String>, grantResults:IntArray){
        when(requestCode){
            REQUEST_CODE_LOCATION->{
                if(grantResults.size>0 && grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    getLocation()
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(activity.applicationContext, "You did not give permissions to get location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    fun stopUpdateLocation(){
        this.fusedLocationClient?.removeLocationUpdates(callbabck)
    }
    fun inicializeLocation(){
        if (validatePermissionsLocation()){
            getLocation()
        }else{
            requestPermissions()
        }
    }
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private fun getLocation() {
        validatePermissionsLocation()
        fusedLocationClient?.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, callbabck, null)
    }
}
```

usage

```
class MapsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {
    var location: Location?=null
    private var mMap: GoogleMap? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps)
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
        location= Location(this, object :locationListener{
            override fun locationResponse(locationResult: LocationResult) {
                mMap?.clear()
                val sydney = LatLng(locationResult.lastLocation.latitude, locationResult.lastLocation.longitude)
                mMap?.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Hi").snippet("Let's go!"))
                mMap?.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 14f))
            }
        })

    }

    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        location?.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
    }
    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        location?.inicializeLocation()
    }
    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        location?.stopUpdateLocation()
    }
}
```

I hope this help you

Comment: I've changed my code into yours and it still doesn't work :( I don't know why, there is only map with 0.0 & 0.0 location... do you have any ideas why? Didi you run this code?

Comment: @Anna Yes, I execute the code in a physical device and emulator before answering. Probably the device is the problem.